Why are the Q and K matrices two separate matrices in attention?
If I understand correctly the attention layer is represented as
$$
\begin{align}
&softmax(\frac{Q K^T}{\sqrt{d_k}}) V  \\
= &softmax(\frac{(s W_q) (s W_k)^T}{\sqrt{d_k}}) V \\
= &softmax(\frac{(s W_q) (W_k^T s^T)}{\sqrt{d_k}}) V \\
= &softmax(\frac{s (W_q W_k^T) s^T}{\sqrt{d_k}}) V \\
\end{align}
$$
Wouldn't it be better to take $W_q W_k^T$ as a single parameter?

dw, you got some "{}" missplaced, fixed for you

Your calculations are correct, though training a whole $W$ is not always equivalent.
We can agree that $W_q, W_k \in R^{n\times m}$, thus $W_{qk} = W_qW_k^T \in R^{n\times n}$
Now, check the parameter count of $W_{qk}$ parametrized like this, and fully parametrized: in the former case, you have $2\cdot(n\cdot m)$ parameters, and in the latter $n^2$. Already here you can see that there might be a difference if $m < \frac{n}{2}$.
in other words, in this case the resulting matrix (the fully parametrized) might be full rank, where instead the factorized one has lower rank

Interestin, I hadn't thought of that. Would it be fair to say that in the special case where  $m \ge \frac{n}{2}$ it's more parameter efficient to  use the combined weights? Is that uncommon in the wild?

@fakedrake yeah i’d say that is more reasonable, tough i’ve not enough experience to say if that’s done usually or not
